# I want to get a condition inside an if running for x seconds

Tags: processing

```java
PFont mono;
float x;
float y;
float speed;
int m=millis();

void setup() {
  size(720, 480);
  background(0);
  mono = createFont("Helvetica", 100);
  textFont(mono);
  text("Ê", 90, 270);
  text("X", 190, 270);
  text("T", 295, 270);
  text("A", 385, 270);
  text("S", 480, 270);
  text("E", 580, 270);
}

void draw() {
  speed+=1.5;
  if (260-speed<250) {
    speed*=-1;
  }
  if (mouseX>85 && 95<mouseX && mouseY>220 && 320>mouseY) {
    background(0);
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("Ê", 90+random(-10, 10), 270-speed);
    fill(255);
    text("X", 190, 270);
    text("T", 295, 270);
    text("A", 385, 270);
    text("S", 480, 270);
    text("E", 580, 270);
  } 
  if (mouseX>185 && 195<mouseX && mouseY>220 && 320>mouseY) {
    background(0);
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("X", 190+random(-10, 10), 270-speed);
    fill(255);
    text("Ê", 90, 270);
    text("T", 295, 270);
    text("A", 385, 270);
    text("S", 480, 270);
    text("E", 580, 270);
  } 
  if (mouseX>290 && 300<mouseX && mouseY>220 && 320>mouseY) {
    background(0);
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("T", 295+random(-10, 10), 270-speed);
    fill(255);
    text("Ê", 90, 270);
    text("X", 190, 270);
    text("A", 385, 270);
    text("S", 480, 270);
    text("E", 580, 270);
  }
  if (mouseX>380 && 390<mouseX && mouseY>220 && 320>mouseY) {
    background(0);
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("A", 385+random(-10, 10), 270-speed);
    fill(255);
    text("S", 480, 270);
    text("E", 580, 270);
    text("Ê", 90, 270);
    text("X", 190, 270);
    text("T", 295, 270);
  }
  if (mouseX>475 && 480<mouseX && mouseY>220 && 320>mouseY) {
    background(0);
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("S", 480+random(-10, 10), 270-speed);
    fill(255);
    text("E", 580, 270);
    text("Ê", 90, 270);
    text("X", 190, 270);
    text("T", 295, 270);
    text("A", 385, 270);
  }
  if (mouseX>575 && 585<mouseX && mouseY>220 && 320>mouseY) {
    background(0);
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("E", 580+random(-10, 10), 270-speed);
    fill(255);
    text("Ê", 90, 270);
    text("X", 190, 270);
    text("T", 295, 270);
    text("A", 385, 270);
    text("S", 480, 270);
  }
}
```

This is my code and i want to make it so that when the mouse has left a certain position it keeps doing the cicle for 5 seconds, and that after that it returns to the position that is the setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18324/i-want-to-get-a-condition-inside-an-if-running-for-x-seconds

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about it a little bit backwards: you don't want to stay inside the `if` statement for 5 seconds. Instead, you want the `if` statement to evaluate to `true` for 5 seconds.

This might sound like nit-picking, but the big difference is that you want this to stay true **between** calls to the `draw()` function.

You can do that using a `boolean` variable, an `int` variable, and the `millis()` function.

**Step 1:** Use a `boolean` variable to keep track of whether you should be doing the thing. Set this to `true` when you want to start doing the thing.

**Step 2:** Use an `int` variable to keep track of when you **started** doing the thing. Set this to `millis()` when you start doing the thing.

**Step 3:** In your `draw()` function, check the `boolean` variable to decide whether to do the thing. If it's `true`, do the thing.

**Step 4:** Also in your `draw()` function, check the `int` variable against the current value of `millis()` to decide if enough time has elapsed. If so, set the `boolean` back to `false`.

Here's a small example that shows a circle for 5 seconds whenever the user clicks:

```java
float circleX;
float circleY;

boolean showCircle = false;
int startTime;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {

  if (millis() > startTime + 5*1000) {
    showCircle = false;
  }

  if (mousePressed) {
    circleX = mouseX;
    circleY = mouseY;
    startTime = millis();
    showCircle = true;
  }

  background(0);

  if (showCircle) {
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

If you still have questions, please work from an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this instead of posting your entire project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm not really good at programming and that example is for a mouse press, and i don't need that in my project. If you could help by showing how it would look like on my project i would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia This program is just an example showing you the general approach. You're going to have to take this approach and adapt it to fit your exact needs. Try breaking it down into the four steps I outlined above.

Comment: i did try but in the mouse press is where you initialize the variables and i want them initialized when i pass with the mouse above the letters and when i try to initialize the variables there e doesn't work like i want it to. I'm really sorry for being this annoying but i'm really not that good at processing

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia It's okay. Slow down. What exactly do you mean when you say it doesn't work like you want it to? If you have a follow-up question, please post an [mcve] in a new question, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I want the letters to shake for 5 seconds after the mouse has left the location of the letter and the return to it's original form

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia Okay great. Which step that I outlined above are you stuck on?

Comment: in step 2, where you start counting the time with millis(), i don't know where to put that piece of code

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia You would put it in the same place where you set your `boolean` variable to `true`, just like in my example.

Comment: ok, I understand that but I want my `boolean` to become true when I put my cursor in a letter and if I start my `boolean` there it does not work

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia Sounds good. What happened when you set your `boolean` variable to `true` inside that `if` statement? Note: You're going to have **separate** `if` statements: one to check when to set your `boolean` variable to `true`, and another that simply checks against that `boolean` variable.

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia I've edited my answer to use a separate `if` statement instead of the `mousePressed()` function. This is pretty much exactly what you need to do, except one of your `if` statements will have more conditions than mine.

Comment: now i have another problem, how can i reset `millis()`? Cause i want the cicle to begin everytime i pass over another letter

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia You don't reset `millis()`. That doesn't make sense, as `millis()` will always give you the current elapsed time. Instead, you'd want to reset `startTime` to the current value of `millis()`. Note that this is exactly what I do: as long as the user has the mouse pressed down, the time will "reset" to the current `millis()` value. If you have follow-up questions, please post a [mcve] in a new question instead of in the comment section.

Comment: Is there any other way we can talk, as i do not have access to chat and i want to send you my code as it is now

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia Like I said, you can post your updated [mcve] in a new question. As long as you tag it with [tag:processing], I'll see it. Please note that this should be a small example (more like my code), not your whole project.

Comment: i can't do a new question, i've reached my great limit of 1 per day :(

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia Then you should probably just wait a day. Try to work from the example I gave you, take your time, and work in small steps. I also have a personal forum at [forum.HappyCoding.io](http://forum.HappyCoding.io) if you want to post there- you'd be the first post.